# Shared vs Static Dim statement?

Tags: .net, vb.net

According to Microsoft documentation on Visual Basic Dim statement.

The Dim statement could  either be Shared, Shadows, Static, and ReadOnly

Statement structure:

`[ <attributelist> ] [ accessmodifier ] [[ Shared ] [ Shadows ] | [ Static ]] [ ReadOnly ]
Dim [ WithEvents ] variablelist`

My questions is:

1. What's the difference between Shared and Static?
2. When one is used over the other?
3. Are there any limitation to using one over the other?

I thought Shared is the same thing as Static.

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/dim-statement

Comment: It says "could be" not "should be". Normally Dim is used inside a method and has no modifiers or attributes.

Comment: *"I thought Shared is the same thing as Static"*. You probably heard that `Shared` in VB is the same as `static` in C#. `Static` in VB is something else. Mind you, `Shared` in VB and `static` in C# mean a single member for the entire type rather than separate instances of the member for each instance of the type, while `Static` in VB means a single instance of the local variable for all instances of the method, so there is some similarity there.

Answer (score 0):

`Static` can only be used for local variables, i.e., variables declared in a method. It makes the variable retain its value between calls. It effectively turns the variable in an instance field of the class visible only inside this method.

`Shared` is applied to members of classes and structs. Such members are then shared between all instances (i.e., objects) of this class or struct.

In C# there is no keyword corresponding to VB's `Static`; howerver, there is a `static` keyword corresponding the VB's `Shared` keyword (which I find a bit confusing).

See:

- [Static (Visual Basic)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/modifiers/static) ([Visual Basic Language Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/))
- [Shared (Visual Basic)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/modifiers/shared) ([Visual Basic Language Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/))

Comment: The VB static works like the C static, I believe.  I think the history of the C# static is that it's carried over from C++, which used that word because they overloaded keywords from C as much as possible to minimize the changes needed to turn valid C code into valid C++ code.

Comment: No, VB `Shared` works like C# `static`. You cannot have a static local variable in C#.

Comment: Um, my comment didn't discuss VB `Shared` at all, and only discussed C# `static` in the context of a common ancestor.  I don't disagree that the current state is potentially confusing, I was just making my best guess at how we got where we are now.

Comment: Yes, but [Static (Visual Basic)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/modifiers/static) can only be applied to local variables. The linked article says: *Specifies that one or more declared local variables are to continue to exist and retain their latest values after termination of the procedure in which they are declared.*

Comment: Indeed, and I believe that `static` in C has the same behavior (confirmed here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/static-variables-in-c/ ).  C++ overloaded `static` (because they wanted to minimize new keywords to minimize changes needed to turn valid C code into valid C++ code) to mean the same thing as it currently means in C#, and C# took its meaning from C++, and now here we are, where `Static` in VB doesn't have a C# equivalent (but is equivalent to `static` in C#'s ancestor C) and `Shared` in VB is equivalent to `static` in C# and class-level `static` in C++.